# Azure loadBalancerInboundNatPool - How to setup

Tags: azure, networking, load-balancing, autoscaling

I've setup a load balancer in my resource-group with a backend pool and inbound nat rules for http and https.

Now when i try to create an auto-scale-set through a template, i have to reference to a "loadBalancerInboundNatPool". But this is, what i can decipher from the error messages, not the same as the InboundNatRules.

[image]

How do i create/find the name of my InboundNatPool, so i can reference it from my template and create my Auto-Scale-Set correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loadBalancerInboundNatPools is in vmss, you need to add this to vmss

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at existing examples doing exactly this thing:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-2-vms-loadbalancer-natrules
https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-vmss-linux-nat

and several others in that repo. I don't really understand your question, but those templates will let you do just what your goal is

Comment: Because i'm starting the load-balancer from the portal, not templates. Only the scale-set is created from a template. Any advice is greatly appreciated

Comment: i dont understand what you are saying. these templates (and various others) will let you deploy vms and availability set and load balancer and nat rules

Comment: I am using the Azure Portal to create and manage the Load Balancer from. Not a template deployment (i do it directly from portal.azure.com). The scale set is created from a custom template due to the requirement of custom managed image. Question is how i add inboundNatPools through the webinterface so i dont have to deploy through a template.

Comment: just add a backendpool and natpools after that?

Comment: The backendpool is not a problem since there is a menu option on the ressource page. But there is no such menu for the natpool. Only natrule

Comment: those are the same, one is for vms, other for vmss